# What does it mean when a variable equals a function?

Tags: javascript, function, coding-style, convention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

In JavaScript, what's the purpose of defining a variable *as* a function? I've seen this convention before and don't fully understand it.

For example, at some point in a script, a function is called like this:

`whatever();`

But where I would expect to see a function named `whatever`, like this:

```
function whatever(){

}
```

Instead I'll see a variable called `whatever` that's defined as a function, like this:

```
var whatever = function(){

}
```

What's the purpose of this? Why would you do this instead of just naming the function?

Comment: They're called anonymous functions: http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Note**: Please see the update at the end of the answer, declarations within blocks became valid (but quite complicated if you're not using strict mode).

---

Here's one reason:

```
var whatever;

if (some_condition) {
    whatever = function() {
        // Do something
    };
}
else {
    whatever = function() {
        // Do something else
    };
}
whatever();
```

You might see code like that in the initialization of a library that has to handle implementation differences (such as differences between web browsers, a'la IE's `attachEvent` vs. the standard `addEventListener`). You cannot do the equivalent with a function declaration:

```
if (some_condition) {
    function whatever() {    // <=== DON'T DO THIS
        // Do something
    }
}
else {
    function whatever() {    // <=== IT'S INVALID
        // Do something else
    }
}
whatever();
```

...they're not specified within control structures, so JavaScript engines are allowed to do what they want, and different engines have done different things. *(Edit: Again, see note below, they're specified now.)*

Separately, there's a big difference between

```
var whatever = function() {
    // ...
};
```

and

```
function whatever() {
    // ...
}
```

The first is a *function expression*, and it's evaluated when the code reaches that point in the step-by-step execution of the context (e.g., the function it's in, or the step-by-step execution of global code). It also results in an *anonymous* function (the variable referring to it has a name, but the function does not, which has implications for [helping your tools to help you](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)).

The second is a *function declaration*, and it's evaluated upon entry to the context, **before** any step-by-step code is executed. (Some call this "hoisting" because something further down in the source happens earlier than something higher up in the source.) The function is also given a proper name.

So consider:

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    console.log("typeof bar = " + typeof bar); // Logs "function"

    function bar() {
    }
}
```

whereas

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    console.log("typeof bar = " + typeof bar); // Logs "undefined"

    var bar = function() {
    };
}
```

In the first example, with the declaration, the declaration is processed *before* the `doSomething` and other stepwise code is run. In the second example, because it's an *expression*, it's executed as part of the stepwise code and so the function isn't defined up above (the variable is defined up above, because [`var` is also "hoisted"](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)).

And winding up: For the moment, you can't do this in general client-side web stuff:

```
var bar = function foo() { // <=== Don't do this in client-side code for now
    // ...
};
```

You *should* be able to do that, it's called a *named function expression* and it's a function expression that gives the function a proper name. But various JavaScript engines at various times have gotten it wrong, and [IE continued to get very wrong indeed until very recently](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html).

---

### Update for ES2015+

As of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), function declarations within blocks were added to the specification.

#### Strict mode

In strict mode, the newly-specified behavior is simple and easy to understand: They're scoped to the block in which they occur, and are hoisted to the top of it.

So this:

```js
"use strict";
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  foo();
  function foo() {
    console.log("low");
  }
} else {
  foo();
  function foo() {
    console.log("high");
  }
}
console.log(typeof foo); // undefined
```

(Note how the calls to the functions are *above* the functions within the blocks.)

...is essentially equivalent to this:

```js
"use strict";
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  let foo = function() {
    console.log("low");
  };
  foo();
} else {
  let foo = function() {
    console.log("high");
  };
  foo();
}
console.log(typeof foo); // undefined
```

#### Loose mode

Loose mode behavior is much more complex and moreover in theory it varies between JavaScript engines in web browsers and JavaScript engines *not* in web browsers. I won't get into it here. Just don't do it. If you insist on function declarations within blocks, use strict mode, where they make sense and are consistent across environments.

Comment: great and usefull, thanks : )

Comment: @DanielAndresAcevedo: Thanks. It was also slightly out of date, I've added a note at the end.

Answer (score 3):

this is so you can store functions in variables and e.g. pass them to other functions as parameters. One example where this is usefull is in writing asynchronous functions which are passed callbacks as arguments

```
var callback = function() { console.log('done', result)}

var dosomething = function(callback) {
    //do some stuff here
    ...
    result = 1;
    callback(result);
}
```

Since functions are objects in javascript you can extend them with properties and methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript are objects; they're *values*, in other words.  Thus you can *always* set a variable to refer to a function regardless of how the function is defined:

```
function foo() { ... }

var anotherFoo = foo;
anotherFoo(); // calls foo
```

Functions are values that can be used as object properties, function parameters, array elements, and anything else a general value can do in JavaScript. They're objects and can have their own properties too.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a function to a variable, you can then pass it around as an argument to other functions, and also extend it to make use of Javascript's Object model.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a functionvariable, using "var", within a function, the variable **can only** be accessed within that function. When you exit the function, the variable is destroyed. These variables are called local variables. You can have local variables with the same name in different functions, because each is recognized only by the function in which it is declared.